# How to check the class belongs to which framework in XCode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, ide

For example, "Reachability",

```
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[Reachability startNotifer] in xxxxx.a(Reachability.o)
```

I get the error like this....I know I just missing import a framework inside this, but how can I check the `Reachability` is from which framework? How can I know it is from `SystemConfiguration`?? instead of Google it, does XCode provide any way to find that out? Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s a linker error, which is solved by linking (as opposed to importing) the framework that exports that symbol. You can easily find out the relevant framework by using the documentation viewer.

For example, if you open the documentation viewer <kbd>⌥⌘?</kbd>, search for `SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback` and open the corresponding documentation page, at the very top of the page you’ll see:

[image]